# Is there a way to unlock an Android device programmatically permanently?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am searching for a way to unlock the device permanently from an app launch. The concept is that I plug in a device via usb to the tablet/phone and the screen unlocks (this is working) and after I exit the app I want the device to return to them home screen. But the thing is that it returns to the lock screen instead of the home screen. Is there a way to do this?

The main idea behind this is to keep the user away from inserting the unlock code multiple times, for no apparent reason.